# MergJSON LiveCode External for iOS standalone setup

Tags: ios, json, livecode

Currently we are only testing LiveCode 7.0.4 to see how it works and if we want to even use it.  In our apps we need JSON from our server and have setup the mergJSON library/External in Livecode. So far, this is working very nicely in standalone tests for both MacOS and Windows.  Today I started doing some simple tests on iOS and I am having a hard time with it.

I found answers where we need to use the Copy Files section in Standalone Settings, and that we need to copy the *.lcext file for mergJSON. Also watched the youtube how-to video that had mergSettings. There are no .nib files for mergJSON. Only .so, .dylib, and .dll, and the .lcext.  I tried to add the .bundle file like the video, but the app will not launch, only black screen. Are other files required for mergJSON? And where do we put them? Do they stay in the same Externals folder structure or in project folder. Also, does an IOS runtime folder need to be created like in Widows/Mac? The app runs, no errors, but no JSON results are returned. I guess I am just a little confused on the Externals setup for iOS.

Just quick notes of our environment.  We have Xcode 6.2 and the iOS Sdk 8.2.  Live Code is 7.0.4 GPL (just testing and learning this way for now, will purchase commercial once I learn more.) I think the mergJSON I have is 1.0.15, downloaded from mergext.com. (which appears to be offline today) I have only tested on the simulator.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to include the lcext file in the copy files section of standalone settings. No need to setup a runtime folder for iOS etc.

Comment: Thanks so much Monte! I'll test that again. My first try, I did include just the lcext file, it wouldn't output any JSON. But I'll add extra output during the procedure, because maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Works!  Actually, my problem was not with mergJSON, although this did answer my question and cleared some confusion.  The main reason it didn't work though, was due to external .livecode stacks that handled all the JSON functions. None of that code would run, until I included them in Copy Files and set path for mobile to use engine path on the "start using" lines. Thanks again!